# Read/write the same object from scripts executed by 2 separate threads in R

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, queue, shared-memory

Problem Description:

I am trying to build an automated trading system in R connecting to Oanda REST API. My Operating System is Windows 10.
The program has two separate infinite looping components through "while (TRUE)": The "trading engine" and the "tick data streaming engine".
The program is organised in such a way that the two components communicate through a queue object created using "R6" package.
The "tick data streaming engine" receives tick FX data from Oanda server. 
It then creates a tick event object from the data and "push" the tick event to the queue using an instance of the queue class created using "R6" package.
The "trading engine" "pop" the queue object and analyses the event object that comes out.
If it is a Tick data event, it makes an analysis to see whether it meets the conditions set by the logic of the trading strategy.
If the popped  tick event meets the conditions, the trading engine creates an order event object 
which is "pushed" to the back of the queue using the same instance of the queue class created using "R6" package.

To this end, I want to run the "trading engine" using one thread and run the "tick data streaming engine" using another thread.
The two separate threads should be able to push to, and pop from the same event queue instance.
My understanding is that the event queue instance object should be a shared object for the two separate threads to have access to it.

Question:

My question is how can I implement a shared object which can be dynamically modified (write/read) by code files running on two separate threads 
or any other construct that can help achieve read/write to the same object from two or more threads?
How can I possibly use other packages such as "mmap" for shared memory implementation or any other package to achieve my objective?

Attempts:

In order to test the feasibility of the program, this is what I tried:
For simplicity and reproducibility, I created a shared object called "sharedMatrix". 
It is a 10 x 1 matrix which will play the role of the event queue instance in my actual Oanda API program. 
I used the "bigmemory" R package to transform the initial matrix "m" into a big.matrix object "x" and attached it so that it could be a shared object: "sharedMatrix". 
By doing this, I was expecting "sharedMatrix" to be "seen" and modified by each thread running the two separate code files.

```
#Codefile1   
for(i in 1:5){
  sharedMatrix[i,1] <- i
}

#Codefile2   
for(j in 6:10){
  sharedMatrix[j,1] <- j
}
```

I sourced the two code files using the "foreach" and "doParallel" R packages by executing the following code:

```
library(doParallel)
library(bigmemory)
library(foreach)

m <- matrix(nrow = 10) # Create 10 x 1 matrix

x <-as.big.matrix(m) #convert m to bigmatrix

mdesc <- describe(x) # get a description of the matrix

cl <- makeCluster(2,outfile = "Log.txt") # Create a cluster of two threads 
#with output file "Log.txt" 
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterExport(cl=cl,varlist=ls()) #export input data to all cores

fileList  <-list("Codefile1.R","Codefile2.R") # a list of script files saved 
#in current working directory
foreach(f=fileList, .packages = "bigmemory") %dopar% {

sharedMatrix <- attach.big.matrix(mdesc) # attach the matrix via shared 
#memory
source(f)  # Source the script files for parallel execution
}
```

To my surprise this is the console output when the above code is executed:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'sharedMatrix' not found"
```

After checking the content of sharedMatrix, I was expecting to see something like this:

```
sharedMatrix[] 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

However this is what I see:

```
sharedMatrix[]
Error: object 'sharedMatrix' not found
```

It seems to me that the worker threads do not "see" the shared object "sharedMatrix".
Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest something like redis. It handles concurrency, provides queue/stack functionality, and can take arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
library(doParallel)
library(bigmemory)
library(foreach)

m <- matrix(nrow = 10) # Create 10 x 1 matrix

x <-as.big.matrix(m) #convert m to bigmatrix

mdesc <- describe(x) # get a description of the matrix

cl <- makeCluster(2,outfile = "Log.txt") # Create a cluster of two threads 
#with output file "Log.txt" 
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterExport(cl=cl,varlist=ls()) #export input data to all cores

fileList  <-list("Codefile1.R","Codefile2.R") # a list of script files saved 
#in current working directory
foreach(f=fileList, .packages = "bigmemory") %dopar% {

  sharedMatrix <- attach.big.matrix(mdesc) # attach the matrix via shared 
  #memory
  source(f, local = TRUE)  # Source the script files for parallel execution
  NULL
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

**Basically, you need the option `local = TRUE` in the `source()` function.**

PS: Also, make sure to stop clusters.

Comment: @Privé Thanks for your help. As it stands using your suggestion" source(f, local = TRUE)", I get this result:                                                         sharedMatrix[]
Error: object 'sharedMatrix' not found. However x[] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. If I attach sharedMatrix just after the following line of code:                                         x <-as.big.matrix(m) #convert m to bigmatrix and again in the foreach loop it all works fine. sharedMatrix[] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickBeuseize You're welcome. PS: Next time you have a question about package bigmemory, make sure to add the tag *r-bigmemory*.